# how can I sign in from my iphone app to facebook account?

Tags: iphone

I want to sign in to facebook using my application, so how do I code it?

Comment: This might help you <br>
Ref URL: http://www.raywenderlich.com/77/how-to-post-on-facebook-with-your-iphone-app <br>
Hope it helped ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook iOS SDK is available [here](https://developers.facebook.com/ios/).

You will have to

- Download the SDK, and install it
- Create a Facebook App in your Facebook developer console, and get a
  Facebook app id.
- In your Xcode project add the Facebook SDK framework files.
- Add the Facebook app id in your projects Info.plist file, and start
  coding.

You could get more information [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/).

Edit : From iOS6 onwards, Apple has a new framework to post into Facebook. It is called Social Framework, and you could find information about it [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Social/Reference/Social_Framework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012233).

Answer (score 2):

Facebook provide an iOS SDK that gives you the ability to sign into Facebook and methods for accessing the GraphAPI.

Check here for information - http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/400